# Is there a relation between music chords and visible light palette

Tags: visible-light, acoustics, wavelength

Ok I have no idea if this is the right stackexchange so if you know who would know please tell me :)

In music there are groups of notes that, when played togheter, are basis to harmony. Since both sounds and light are waves (at least light acts like one). Is there a relation between the proportion of wavelength in an arbitrary chord and light color palette.

ex, if C,E,G (the musical notes) are all 1.3 times shorter then the previous note. Could we extrapolate the proportion to visible light and make nice colorpalette?
Has this been done before ?

Edit: I found the formula used to calculate note frequency
f(n)=440*2^((n-49)/12)

Comment: here's what you do, assign a 20Hz sound to 700nm and a 20000Hz sound to 340nm. Then apply a linear scale to assign colours to sounds appropriately based on that. Let me know how it turns out

Comment: Here the problem though, I'm colorblind, so I wouldn't be able to determine if it generates nice color palette :(, but i could ask someone who isn't :P

Comment: Oh, I didn't say it would be nice. It would be chromatically representative of the audio frequencies. I really hope it would be nice, but we can't always have everything. That said, if you could figure out how to rig a camera and a speaker such that it did the backwards conversion of this, you might be able to market it to other colour-blind people

Comment: Blue light + red light looks like purple.  This seems like the "chord" analogy you're looking for.

Comment: A bit off topic, but.. Our eyes perceive a single color even when multiple discreet wavelengths are present. The same isn't true of sound.

Comment: @BMS, not really off topic, because in visible light there's black and white... ok so black could be "no sound". but then what is white ? Maybe there is no relation between the 2.

Comment: @user2475269 White could be like... white noise.

Comment: Note that your "equation" is stated to be a function of $x$ but contains no $x$ on the RHS. I presume $n$ is supposed to be $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is no relation. While at least some chords have a nice physical basis - octaves are literally harmonics of each other - human perception of color has very little connection to the physics of light. Color is cyclical: we see high-frequency blues as near low-frequency reds with mixed-frequency purples in between, so there is no equivalent of an octave at all. The closest equivalent to a fifth would be something like complementary colors, which are actually quite "dissonant" instead of harmonious.

Perceived color is also three-dimensional, where pitch is one-dimensional, and there are multiple different color spaces (RGB vs HSV, for example) that arrange colors in very different ways.

If you want to create a palettes that will look nice to folks with color vision, there is plenty of graphic design advice out there. Unfortunately, if you want to understand intuitively what makes such a palette look good, an analogy to sound can't help very much.

Comment: The goal wasn't to make a colorblind friendly palette as i know a couple of ways to do that already, I was just curious to know if there was a relation between the 2. Thank you

Comment: I might be inclined to argue that pitch is many-dimensional. Color is a three-dimensional space because we have 3 types of cones in our eyes that respond (sort of) independently. But the cochlea frequency-analyzes sound into about as many components as there are bundles of stereocilia. The space of pure sinusoidal tones is 1D, but the space of "sounds" is very much richer.

Comment: Vision is also many-dimensional in the same way - we have many more than three light-sensing retinal cells. I think most people would view pitch combinations as analogous to color combinations in visual field. Subtle variations about a single pitch (like violin notes) are similar to texture on a single object, while pitch combinations that register as multiple distinct sounds are like color patterns that register as distinct objects. But I guess it's a matter of personal interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

As a physics & music major I've thought about this a lot.

Our visible light range doesn't even cover one octave (400nm - 700nm), but you can see how 400nm light (violet) almost completes the octave from 700nm light (red). Perhaps if we could see 350nm light we'd perceive it similarly to red? I think there's an evolutionary advantage to our eyes not "completing the octave" because if we did we could confuse certain types of materials (hard to distinguish 350nm red from 700nm red).

Our eyes have incredible direction resolution (we can identify where different colors are coming from extremely well), but poor superposition resolution (we see two colors together as one mixed color). Our ears have fuzzy direction resolution (we can't use our hearing to get around) but great superposition resolution (identifying instruments in an orchestra, etc.).

So I think that's why we find certain superpositions of sound waves pleasant to our ears (music), but different spatial placements of light wave frequencies pleasant to our eyes (paintings). Think of a song as a painting that instead of having light waves mapped over two spatial dimensions, has sound waves mapped over one spatial dimension and one time dimension.